# Zoho Books Api get roles list

Tags: laravel

I'm looking for an API that allows me to retrieve the list of roles in Zoho Books, but I haven't been able to find it. If anyone could provide guidance on how to obtain the list of Zoho Books roles or share a helpful link to the relevant API documentation, I would greatly appreciate it. My main objective is to retrieve the roles associated with Zoho Books. Thank you in advance for your assistance.

Comment: is [this](https://www.zoho.com/books/help/settings/users.html)?

Comment: because I don't see any request to pull the [roles](https://www.zoho.com/books/api/v3/users/#overview).

Comment: zoho says "When you create a Zoho Books account, you become the default admin of your organization. Once you are an admin, you can add multiple users with different roles to your organization." from here i can understand only an admin can create a user and admin can define the roles of user. once you are an admin, Here’s how you can create user and define roles:

    Go to Settings > Users & Roles.
    Click the Invite User in the top right corner of the page.
    Enter the email address, name and the role of the user you’re going to invite to your organization.
    Click Save.